# Summing all numbers from JSON API response in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I need help summing all the numbers from JSON that I get from an API response and saving them in a variable that I can output in template...

This is what my JSON that I get looks like:

```
[
    {
        "count": 495,
        "label": "Ticket",
        "user_id": "42807"
    },
    {
        "count": 248,
        "label": "Hotel",
        "user_id": "42807"
    },
    {
        "count": 75,
        "label": "Insurance",
        "user_id": "42807"
    },
]
```

This is how I'm getting the data from service in my component.ts file:

```
  noOfPurchases: number;

  getSingleCustomerPurchases() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getSingleCustomerPurchases(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.purchasedProd = data;
        // console.log(this.purchasedProd);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

I have tried using .map function but I was getting the error *Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number'.* How would I go about summing all the numbers of "count" together?

Comment: Based on existing answers it's somewhat obvious that your `data` is not actually an array as you described. Can you actually let `console.log(this.purchasedProd)` run and share what's being logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your's component declare a variable which you would like to use in template
`public countSum:number = 0`
Then in the subscription you do it like that:

```
getSingleCustomerPurchases() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getSingleCustomerPurchases(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.purchasedProd = data;
        this.countSum = 0;
        this.purchasedProd.forEach(value => this.countSum += value.count)
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Getting this error: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'CustomerPurchases'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce array method

```js
this.purchasedProd = data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr.count, 0)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'CustomerPurchases'.